# Sort PHP multi-dimensional array based on value in inner array?

Tags: php, sorting

I'm trying to sort my PHP hashtable based on a specific value in the inner array.  The data structure looks like this:

```
print_r($mydata);

Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [type] => suite
        [name] => A-Name
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [type] => suite
        [name] => C-Name
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [type] => suite
        [name] => B-Name
    )
)
```

I've tried **ksort**, **sort**, **usort** but nothing seems to work.  I'm trying to sort based on the **name key** two-levels down.

This was my attempt using usort:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $b['name'] - $a['name'];
}

usort($mydata, "cmp");
```

Is there an easy way to do this or do I need to write a custom sort function?

Comment: so how did you try usort?

Comment: I added my code in the question.

Comment: Subtracting a string from a string?!? No wonder it didn't work, did you look at the examples on the phpdocs web page? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php - specifically example #2

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Thinking,more useful and practical 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

```
function array_sort($array, $on, $order=SORT_ASC){

    $new_array = array();
    $sortable_array = array();

    if (count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                    if ($k2 == $on) {
                        $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
            }
        }

        switch ($order) {
            case SORT_ASC:
                asort($sortable_array);
                break;
            case SORT_DESC:
                arsort($sortable_array);
                break;
        }

        foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
            $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
    }

    return $new_array;
}
```

How to use

```
 $list = array(
   array( 'type' => 'suite', 'name'=>'A-Name'),
   array( 'type' => 'suite', 'name'=>'C-Name'),
   array( 'type' => 'suite', 'name'=>'B-Name')
 );

$list = array_sort($list, 'name', SORT_ASC);

array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(5) "suite" ["name"]=> string(6) "A-Name"    } [2]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(5) "suite" ["name"]=> string(6) "B-Name" } [1]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(5) "suite" ["name"]=> string(6) "C-Name" } }
```

Comment: That is a terrifically overcomplicated solution.

Comment: @deceze Hi! Thanks for comment and downvote. Could you prove your opinion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `usort($mydata, function ($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']); })` — given that this works perfectly fine, yes, I’d say yours is over complicated.

Comment: @deceze yes, of course. But above ( mine ) is more "common" solution. I could say e.g. 100 situaitions ( actually, infinitely) - where my solution will work without any changes. Single solution. You will write 100 usort-functions ( the same - actually, infinitely). Of course, for unique situation - unique solution. There is just "common" solution. Ok. I have understood you. Maybe, do you write every time for each new project classes like `Response`, `Request`, `Controller` etc. ?

Comment: 1) For such a short one-liner it’s not all that necessary to write something generic, hardly comparable to MVC infrastructure. 2) Even for a generic function this is pretty complicated; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22829326/476.

Comment: @deceze I checking you link..... ))) You made my day. P.S. ok, I have understood U. Thanks for good mood for a whole day ))).

Comment: @deceze Actually, your solution from link looks really terrible (for me). And your words `....a terrifically overcomplicated solution` now are sounding very funny. Have a nice day!)

Comment: There's complicated because it's doing something complicated and the code is dense (my example), and then there's complicated because it's doing something needlessly complex for something that could be done in a much simpler way (yours)…

Comment: @deceze Ok, np. Sorry, I`m stopping discuss because I have heart your opinion - your comments & downvote. And understood your seeing this problem (sorting multi-array). Ok. Have a nice day!

Comment: I combined both your solutions and used, Thanks @deceze @voodoo417

```function array_sort($array, $on, $order = SORT_DESC){usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($on, $order) {switch ($order) {case SORT_ASC:return strcmp($a[$on], $b[$on]);case SORT_DESC:return strcmp($b[$on], $a[$on]);}});return $array;}```

Answer (score 13):

Try this usort function:

```
    function cmp($a, $b){
        if ($a == $b)
            return 0;
        return ($a['name'] < $b['name']) ? -1 : 1;
    }

$my_array = array(
0 => array
    (
        'type' => 'suite'
        ,'name' => 'A-Name'
    )
,1 => array
    (
        'type' => 'suite'
        ,'name' => 'C-Name'
    )
,2 => array
    (
        'type' => 'suite'
        ,'name' => 'B-Name'
    )
);


usort($my_array, "cmp");
```

If you using it in a class, the second parameter changes to an array like this:

```
usort($my_array, array($this,'cmp'));
```

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks.

Comment: uasort($my_array, function ($a, $b){
            if ($a == $b)
                return 0;
            return ($a['name'] < $b['name']) ? -1 : 1;
        });

Answer (score 4):

[array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) - Sort multiple or multi-dimensional arrays.

```php
array_multisort(array_column($mydata, 'name'), SORT_ASC, $mydata);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/615mM)

Comment: this is more friendly than PHP manual: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBaHBmZLDxY

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
$a=array(
array('a'=>5,'b'=>7),array('c'=>4,'d'=>2),array('e'=>0,'f'=>12)

    );
function cmp_sort($x,$y){           //your function to compare two keys
if($x===$y)
    return 0;
else
    return ($x<$y?1:-1);
}

uasort($a,'cmp_sort');    //call user-defined compare function
print_r($a);              //printing the sorted array


?>
```

Output=>

> *Array ( [2] => Array ( [e] => 0 [f] => 12 ) [1] => Array ( [c] => 4 [d] => 2 ) [0] => Array ( [a] => 5 [b] => 7 ) )*

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->aasort($array,"key");

function aasort (&$array, $key) {
    $sorter=array();
    $ret=array();
    reset($array);

    foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
        $sorter[]=$va[$key];
    }

    arsort($sorter);

    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
        $ret[]=$array[$ii];
    }

    return $array=$ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this recursive mode, that I used in Magento REST API:

```
$parameters = ['searchCriteria' => ['currentPage' => 1, 'pageSize' => 20]];
$parameters['searchCriteria']['filter_groups'][0]['filters'][0] = ['condition_type' => 'from', 'field' => 'updated_at', 'value' => '2017-01-01T00:00:00'];
$parameters['searchCriteria']['filter_groups'][1]['filters'][0] = ['condition_type' => 'to', 'field' => 'updated_at', 'value' => '2017-12-31T23:59:59']; 

function sortArrayByKeyAsc($_params){
    if(is_array($_params)){
        uksort($_params, 'strnatcmp');
        foreach ($_params as $key => $value){
            if(is_array($value)){
                $_params[$key] = sortArrayByKeyAsc($value);
            }
        }
    }
    return $_params;
}
```