# How to sort php array by multiple fields using usort

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.4

```
usort($childs, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['parent_id'] - $b['parent_id'];
});
```

Here I'm sorting it by 1 field, how can I add more fields to sort them?, Like if it was the `ORDER BY field1, field2, field3` in Mysql

Comment: this may shed some light http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582649/php-sort-array-by-two-field-values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
usort($childs, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['field1'] == $b['field1']) {
        if ($a['field2'] == $b['field2']) {
            return $a['field3'] < $b['field3'] ? -1 : 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
        return $a['field2'] < $b['field2'] ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return $a['field1'] < $b['field1'] ? -1 : 1;
});
```

**EDIT**

a slightly more generic solution (untested)

```
$sorts = array('field1' => 'asc', 'field2' => 'asc', 'field3' => 'asc');

usort($childs, function($a, $b) use (array $sorts = array()) {
    foreach($sorts as $field => $direction) {
        if ($a[$field] != $b[$field]) {
            if ($direction == 'asc') {
                return $a[$field] < $b[$field] ? -1 : 1;
            }
            return $a[$field] < $b[$field] ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't `if ($a[1] != $b[1]) return ...; if ($a[2] != $b[2]) return ...` be much more readable...? :)

Comment: Why additional logic and not just `return  $a[..] - $b[..];`?

Comment: @deceze - probably, just trying to provide a literal answer to OP's question using usort() rather than array_multisort().... and with an eye to making it more generic by passing an array (['field1' => 'asc', 'field2' => 'asc', 'field3' => 'asc']) in as well via `use`... though I'm not sure I have the time to make that effort at the moment

Comment: Especially in a `usort` callback, I wouldn't use this right-indenting nested `if` style. Also, if you're comparing numbers, `$a - $b` is fine for returning < 0, 0 and > 0. For strings I'd use `strcmp`, which accomplishes the same. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22829326/476

Comment: Yes, strcmp is definitely better all round for comparing strings, when you know they're strings