# How I can reorder array values by first index? [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have this problem.

I want to order array results by the first, second, or third...values.

For example:

```
$lib = array
        (
          0 => array(
                      "Title" => "The God",
                      "Genre" => "Comedy",
                      "Year"  => 1999
                    ),
          1 => array(
                      "Title" => "The Mexican",
                      "Genre" => "Western",
                      "Year"  => 2010
                    ),
          2 => array(
                      "Title" => "The Oasis",
                      "Genre" => "Cry",
                      "Year"  => 2001
                    );
        );
```

For example: Order all arrays values by Genre, Year... alphabetically or by date.

Comment: Question has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value

Comment: By order, do you mean sort or shuffle?

Comment: Or there : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16306693/1720332

Comment: To be more clear, can you plz post your desired output?