# How to sort associative array by value of defined key PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Want to sort array by value of key, but can't find solution in web.

I want in PHP to sort this array DESC by key is_paid so FROM original array:

```
[user_courses] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [paid_course_id] => 1
                [course_name] => english
                [course_label] => English
                [is_paid] => 1
                [time] => 1378925144
                [voucher] => 0
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [paid_course_id] => 2
                [course_name] => spanish
                [course_label] => English
                [is_paid] => 0
                [time] => 1379073137
                [voucher] => 0
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [paid_course_id] => 3
                [course_name] => russian
                [course_label] => Russian
                [is_paid] => 1
                [time] => 1452277777
                [voucher] => 0


    )
)
```

To become:

```
[user_courses] => Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [paid_course_id] => 1
        [course_name] => english
        [course_label] => English
        [is_paid] => 1
        [time] => 1378925144
        [voucher] => 0
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [paid_course_id] => 3
        [course_name] => russian
        [course_label] => Russian
        [is_paid] => 1
        [time] => 1452277777
        [voucher] => 0


)

[2] => Array
    (
        [paid_course_id] => 2
        [course_name] => spanish
        [course_label] => English
        [is_paid] => 0
        [time] => 1379073137
        [voucher] => 0
    )


)
```

So first to list all the items of the array where have is_paid 1 and at the bottom of the array to put is_paid 0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306416/sort-php-multi-dimensional-array-based-on-key this would be helpful.

Comment: `usort($myArray['user_courses'], function($a, $b) { return $a['paid_course_id'] > $b['paid_course_id']; });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['paid_course_id'] > $b['paid_course_id'];
}

usort($courseArray['user_courses'], 'sortOrder');
```

or with anonymous function

```
usort($courseArray['user_courses'], function($a, $b) {
    return $a['paid_course_id'] > $b['paid_course_id'];
});
```