# How to sort array using object element in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have following `php array` object:

```
"requests": [
{           
   "id": 111,
   "time: 123123123,
   "data": "testc"
},    
{                  
   "id":  200 ,
   "time: 433123123,
   "data": "testb"
},    
{
   "id":  300 ,
   "time:  33123123,
   "data": "testb"
}
]
```

I want to sort it by `requests->time` only. How to do it?

I don't want sort by `id`. All data should be sort as per `time ASC`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306416/sort-php-multi-dimensional-array-based-on-key

Comment: Use [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: if you are geting this data from query then use `ORDER BY time ASC` there only. otherwise use `usort()`

Comment: get reference here    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value

Comment: Using objects (as asked) - maybe interesting? https://eval.in/611600

Comment: people not responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use your own sort method with [usort()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.usort.php)

**Solution** :

```
<?php
function sortByTimeASC($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->time == $b->time) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->time < $b->time) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = json_decode('[{"id": 111,"time": 123123123,"data": "testc"},{ "id":200 ,"time":433123123,"data":"testb"},{"id":300,"time":33123123,"data":"testb"}]');

usort($a, "sortByTimeASC");
print_r($a);
?>
```

[Live example](https://3v4l.org/JvAT5)

Answer (score 2):

supposing you have that array in a `$requests` variable, the following should work

```
<?php
    function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        return strcmp($a["time"],$b["time"]);
    }
    usort($requests, "cmp");

    //print for test
    while (list($key, $value) = each($requests)) {
        echo "\$requests[$key]: " . $value["time"] . "\n";
    }

?>
```