# sort multidimensional array by sub value and maintain main index

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like this.

```
arr[4]=array('name' => 'ab', 'aid' => 1 'qty' => 10);
arr[5]=array('name' => 'ac', 'aid' => 3 'qty' => 15);
arr[3]=array('name' => 'ad', 'aid' => 2 'qty' => 100);
arr[2]=array('name' => 'ae', 'aid' => 2 'qty' => 150);
```

and I need to sort them by the 'aid' but don't change the main index like this.

```
arr[4]=array('name' => 'ab', 'aid' => 1 'qty' => 10);
arr[2]=array('name' => 'ae', 'aid' => 2 'qty' => 150);
arr[3]=array('name' => 'ad', 'aid' => 2 'qty' => 100);
arr[5]=array('name' => 'ac', 'aid' => 3 'qty' => 15);
```

is that possible? what should I do? thanks.

Comment: WHat's your php version?

Comment: If you are using php5.5 or higher, you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php . By the way, this is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306416/sort-php-multi-dimensional-array-based-on-key

Answer (score 0):

From PHP manual

```
<?php
    $data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 2);
    $data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 1);
    $data[] = array('volume' => 85, 'edition' => 6);
    $data[] = array('volume' => 98, 'edition' => 2);
    $data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 6);
    $data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 7);
?>
```

In this example, we will order by volume descending, edition ascending.

We have an array of rows, but array_multisort() requires an array of columns, so we use the below code to obtain the columns, then perform the sorting.

```
<?php
    // Obtain a list of columns
    foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
        $volume[$key]  = $row['volume'];
        $edition[$key] = $row['edition'];
    }

    // Sort the data with volume descending, edition ascending
    // Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
    array_multisort($volume, SORT_DESC, $edition, SORT_ASC, $data);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

**Edit**

For your need you requested:

```
$arr[4]=array('name' => 'ab', 'aid' => 1, 'qty' => 10);
$arr[5]=array('name' => 'ac', 'aid' => 3, 'qty' => 15);
$arr[3]=array('name' => 'ad', 'aid' => 2, 'qty' => 100);
$arr[2]=array('name' => 'ae', 'aid' => 2, 'qty' => 150);

$keyPositions = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $keyPositions[] = $key;
}


foreach ($arr as $key => $row) {
    $aid[$key]  = $row['aid'];
}

array_multisort($aid, SORT_ASC, $arr);

$sortedArray = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $sortedArray[$keyPositions[$key]] = $value;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($sortedArray);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: This example exactly represents your situation.

Comment: thank you for your answer. it is said on the manual that "Associative (string) keys will be maintained, but numeric keys will be re-indexed." is there any way numeric keys maintained?

Comment: numberic keys or values?

Comment: numeric keys on main index

Comment: Oh I see. I think you have to code a little bit. You can not do that just with a function call. Do you want to try? or I can come up with a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121097/discussion-between-eexbee-and-wildashfihana).