# how can i sort 2 dimensional array based on index array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array in PHP like this :

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => black
            [2] => brown
            [1] => red
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [2] => car
        [0] => bicycle
        [1] => motorcycle
    )
```

)

How do I get the array, like this :

Result:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => black
            [1] => red
            [2] => brown
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (

        [0] => bicycle
        [1] => motorcycle
        [2] => car
    )
```

)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try like this perhaps:

```
$arr=array(
    array(2=>'red',1=>'green',3=>'black'),
    array(1=>'pink',3=>'blue',2=>'yellow')
);
array_walk( $arr, function(&$v,$k){
    ksort($v);
});
echo '<pre>', print_r( $arr, true ), '</pre>';
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => green
            [2] => red
            [3] => black
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => pink
            [2] => yellow
            [3] => blue
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the krsort() function to sort an associative array in descending order, according to the key.

Comment: ksort only exist in 1 dimension array, how to implement ksort on multidimensional array? thank's

Comment: Have a look for answers of this question ,  may be it will help you  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306416/sort-php-multi-dimensional-array-based-on-key)