# How can I sort the keys of a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["12345"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["orange"]=>
      string(46) "test.jpg"
      ["blue"]=>
      string(46) "test2.jpg"
      ["green"]=>
      string(46) "test3.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to sort it by key:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      if(is_array($value)){
           foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
                usort($v);
                foreach ($v as $fileIterator => $fileData) {
                     echo $fileIterator;
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

This is the result

```
orange
blue
green
```

But I expect the order to be

```
blue
green
orange
```

Comment: change this `$value as $k => $v` to `$value as $k => &$v` and `ksort()` not `usort()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort PHP multi-dimensional array based on key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306416/sort-php-multi-dimensional-array-based-on-key)

Comment: No this is not a dublicate. Because This question is sorting the values not the key

Comment: @Jarla you will be sorting key only at the end. Not the value. The value itself is a array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: @Abhishek Yes, thank you! This is working, I guess

Comment: @Jarla do accept the answer then. Happy Coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,
You have to sort based on key so use `ksort()`. While using `foreach()` the duplicate of array is processed. In order to make changes in original array use `'&'`(calling by reference)

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      if(is_array($value)){
           foreach ($value as $k => &$v) {
                ksort($v);
                foreach ($v as $fileIterator => $fileData) {
                     echo $fileIterator;
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: @IncredibleHat was about to add that. Thanks for pointing it out though.!