# How to sort array after combine with specification key is name and value alphabetical in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have some problem with sort data array by alphabetical

I've read about the sort in the following link
[PHP 5 Sorting Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp)

And here I have tried some functions and not as expected, look at the following picture
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3goy.png)

But my question is what if i want to sort array from second key then sort alphabetically

Sample Array

```
[0] => Array (
    [id] => 46759
    [nama] => Albino
)
[1] => Array (
    [id] => 46772
    [nama] => Saputra
)
[2] => Array (
    [id] => 46710
    [nama] => Soni Putra
)
[3] => Array (
    [id] => 46760
    [nama] => Abian
)
```

And i want result sort by "nama" so result of that's array like this

```
- Abian
- Albino
- Saputra
- Soni Putra
```

I try using `sort()` or `asort()` with many array but the letter "A" is still some that are not sorted according to the order of the letters, is there any other solution to solve this problem ?

**UPDATE**

I have solution from this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306416/sort-php-multi-dimensional-array-based-on-key), thanks for answering my question.

Comment: You can start with http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php to build a custom sorting callback, within your function you can interrogate the 'nama' array key and perform a strcmp or attempt to sort using http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: the answer can be find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306416/sort-php-multi-dimensional-array-based-on-key

Comment: @azizsagi i try your link and work but why just first word can be sort ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of a custom sorting callback using [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and [strcmp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php).

This is the cleanest and simplest way to perform this type of sorting.

note: [strnatcmp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php) is available too if you need "natural sorting"

```
$array = array(
  array(
    'id' => 46759,
    'nama' => 'Albino'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 46772,
    'nama' => 'Saputra'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 46710,
    'nama' => 'Soni Putra'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 46760,
    'nama' => 'Abian'
  )
);

usort( $array, function( $a, $b ){
  return strcmp( $a['nama'], $b['nama'] );
});
```

---

If you want re-usable

```
function sortByKey( &$array, $key ){
  usort( $array, function( $a, $b ) use ( $key ){
    return strcmp( $a[ $key ], $b[ $key ] );
  });
}

sortByKey( $array, 'nama' );
```